# How do I implement this for my android app

Tags: android

Hi Guys I recently have seen an app that allows you to copy a url of and instagram post and share it to the app from instagram

[you can see what I mean here:](https://youtu.be/8lr8EgCvLTw?t=6)

How do i make it so my app can do this from a web browser, I want theuser to be able to copy the url and send it to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use intent to receive the url from instagram.
Now is your time to customise it :)

First, You need to update your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

2. add this to your MainActivity:

   ```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
       String action = intent.getAction();
       String type = intent.getType();
       if ("android.intent.action.SEND".equals(action) && 
               type != null && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
           Log.println(Log.ASSERT,
                   "shareablTextExtra",intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT"));
       }
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the users web browser as I would like the user to be able to send the current url they are on to my app.

Comment: Depends on your browser. I guess u are using Chrome, so click on "3 dots" option menu and chose "share". And If my solution answer your question plz accept it so others could find it.

Comment: Ben is it possible to do it with javascript?

Comment: Try this: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-the-web-share-api/ 
upvote plz if it helped you

Comment: Hi ben I think You have sent me the code for the wrong thing , I would like my app to recieve share data from chrome using javascript.